# Getting negative the correct answer in $\iint_R e^{x+y}dA, R=\{(x,y)\quad |\quad|x|+|y|\leq 1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_R e^{x+y}dA, R=\{(x,y)\quad |\quad|x|+|y|\leq 1\}$$

I have tried setting $u=y-x$ and $v=x+y$. Then I calculated the jacobian as $-\frac{1}{2}$. So the integral becomes:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1e^vdvdu=e^{-1}-e$$

However, the book says that the answer should be $e-e^{-1}$. Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change of variable is done with the absolute value of the Jacobian.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the answer!